# Using two html index pages with the same name but different extensions

Tags: html, indexing

I'm using two index pages with different contents and different extensions on my html site root folder, html and htm. The problem is that sometimes when I open my site in Chrome (or other browsers) I see the htm index file and sometimes vice versa. For various reasons (e.g avoiding 302 or 404 errors), I can't delete the htm index file. My questions are: 
1. Why is this happening? 
2. Which extension is more important in terms of priority in browsers view?
3. What are my options to overcome this problem?

I have checked my html index file with applications like HTMLValidator and other services to make sure that there is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: What server are you using? I believe you can control which index file is used in your server configuration file

Answer (score 0):

The priority about index files is default set by web server. You can change it in configuration of web server, or you can use .htaccess file to change that priority. Documentation can be found here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Simply add .htaccess file to your web root dir with content:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm
```

In specific order you want.